# Combine syntax with semantic search in Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp, word-embedding

I'm trying to make a simple searcher with Elastic using `dense-vectors` with trained embeddings to make better suggestions when I don't have in my database the exact terms but I do have something semantically similar.
For example: Lets assume I have in my database the following products:

`['red apple', 'yellow banana', 'green apple', 'car']`

If someone queries `'apple'` I would like to see the following ordered results (assuming the order is given by the cosineSimilarity between the embedded query and each product):

`['red apple', 'green apple', 'yellow banana' (assuming it's closer to apple because they are fruits), 'car']`.

**So far I could make the following elastic queries (previously preprocessing and calculating the query embedding) having the above results**:

1. First option:

```
    {
        "size": 20,
        "query": {
            "script_score": {
                "query" : {
                        "match": { "product_name": 'apple' }
                    },
                "script": {
                    "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.queryVector, doc['Embedding']) + 1.0",
                    "params": {
                        "queryVector": query_vector
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Gives me the result: `['red apple', 'green apple']` (the results not containing apple are not being displayed)

2. Second option:

```
    {
        "size": 20,
        "query": {
            "script_score": {
                "query" : {
                        "match_all": {}
                    },
                "script": {
                    "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.queryVector, doc['Embedding']) + 1.0",
                    "params": {
                        "queryVector": query_vector
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It's giving me the following results: `['red apple', 'banana', 'green apple', 'car']` (banana appears before the second apple). I think this is the proper way but I can't make it to show first the things that match syntactically first.

I would appreciate any help.